# Reduce constructor arguments whilst keeping service usage explicit?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am using C#, but my question applies to any OOP language.

I have many different objects that consume a range of services. I would like the way these services are accessed to satisfy a few constraints, but I am struggling to figure out a good design.

- I would like the usage of these services to be explicit
- An object should never be in an invalid state (services should be passed on construction)
- Service usage should be clear
- Code repetition should be minimal

I think these are all good aims, but they are proving difficult to achieve in practice. My current approach is a sort of *dependency-injection-by-hand*:

```
class MyObject
{
    // ... 

    public MyObject(IFooService fooService, IBarService barService)
    {
        this.fooService = fooService;
        this.barService = barService;
    }
}
```

So far so good. But what happens when I have lots of service dependencies? I have dozens of objects, some of which need to access many services.

I considered building a "service container" object and passing that in:

```
class Services
{
    // ... 

    public IFooService FooService
    {
        get { return this.fooService; } 
    }

    public IBarService BarService
    {
        get { return this.barService; } 
    }

    public Services(IFooService fooService, IBarService barService)
    {
        this.fooService = fooService;
        this.barService = barService;
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    // ...

    public MyObject(Services services)
    {
        this.services = services;
    }
}
```

This saves on typing, but it obscures the services that an object actually uses. Given the constructor, `MyObject` might use *any* of the them!

- What are some common approaches to avoiding this problem?
- Is my problem indicative of a more fundamental design issue?
- Is this really a problem at all? Should I relax some of my design goals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be indicative of 2 problems

1. the services to inject are too fine-grained (for example, if you have a service to create a Foo, and a different one to update a Foo and a third one to delete a Foo), leading to many dependencies.
2. or, more probably, the object using the service is too coarse-grained, and has too many responsibilities. For example, if half of the methods use a set of services and the other half uses another set of services, it's probably a good indication that the object could be splitted in two classes.

Anyway, if you feel your class is not too complex, that you can read, maintain it and test it, I wouldn't bother too much about the number of dependencies. I prefer having a clear, explicit set of dependencies rather than relying on a God object acting as a factory of services and depending on everything. That will hurt testability and readability.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Seemann described this problem with solution  [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

In summary:

1. Make sure you're not breaking [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
2. Refactor dependencies using aggregate services - **Facade Service**

It'll bring another abstraction into your code, but It is probable that extracted behaviour will describe Domain Concepts that **should** be separated anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I considered building a "service container" object"*

Like you noticed already, that just shifts the problem somewhere else, but doesn't really solve it.

There is a similar design pattern, commonly called ["Parameter Object"](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html)… but I don't think it truly applies here. According to the article referenced in the previous sentence, it applies only when you have…

> *"…a particular group of parameters that tend to be passed together."*

Therefore, the Parameter Object pattern only applies in your case if you have several classes that all rely on the same combination of service components (which is rather unlikely if your constructor parameter list gets really long).

> *"What happens when I have lots of service dependencies?"*

If you have so many service dependencies that your constructor parameter list becomes a unwieldy monstrosity, then *perhaps* your class has too many responsibilities, i.e. tries to do too many things and you should break it up into several smaller classes.

I cannot quite remember where I read it, and I am not saying I fully agree, but some smart guy once claimed that any object should not have more than two fields / references to other objects. This is just to show that some people take the "single responsibility principle" very seriously and go to extremes (IMHO) to achieve this.